# max value of column in different row excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the highest value of column B for each set of names in column A and return the max value and it's corresponding name.
each set of names are separated by an empty column.

Can anyone help me with use of vba or without?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Which excel functions are you familiar with? Also, do you mean each set of names is separated by an empty row?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column A has names up to row 100, and column B has values, and cell C1 has the name you are checking for the "max value" [ie: C1 says Brenda, and you want to find the highest value in column B where column A says "Brenda"]

```
=MAX(IF(C1=A1:A100,B1:B100,""))
```

This is an Array Formula. It works by individually comparing C1 with each row in column A. Where there is a match, it provides the value in column B. Note that Array formulas must be confirmed with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, rather than just ENTER, whenever the cell is changed.

Comment: Ya the original question is a bit of a mess; you could be right.